# SetUp method failed while running tests from teamcity

Tags: nunit, teamcity, watin

I am successfuly running tests locally via nunit. But when I try to run them through teamcity some tests are passed but some failed by giving the following error.

SetUp method failed. System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800704a6.
   at WatiN.Core.IE.CreateNewIEAndGoToUri(Uri uri, LogonDialogHandler logonDialogHandler, Boolean createInNewProcess)
   at WatiN.Core.IE..ctor()
   at test.Setup() in C:\Tests.vb:line 14

Comment: If you remove the use of WatiN from your tests, do your NUnit test cases pass without error?

Comment: Related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364970/failed-due-to-the-following-error-800704a6-while-trying-to-read-data-from-a-text

Comment: Another related post http://stackoverflow.com/a/8797600/75963

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this has been resolved or not but I was having the same error in 2 different test fixtures 1 written in C# the other written in VB.NET.

For the C# fixture all I need to do to resolve the issue is when I create a new instance of WatIn.IE, I added the second parameter to:   IE var ie = new IE(url, **true**)
The "true" tells WatIn to "createInNewProcess"  which opens the next IE in a new process.

This, however, did not work for the test fixture written in VB.NET for some reason.
For this fixture I had to call a method in one of our C# libraries to force an IE closure in each Tests "TearDown" method.
The following C# code did the trick:

```
public static void CloseInternetExplorers()
{
  var processes = from process in Process.GetProcesses()
                  where process.ProcessName == "iexplore"
                  select process;

  foreach (var process in processes)
  {
    while (!process.HasExited)
    {
      process.Kill();
      process.WaitForExit();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run the tests via Nunit on the teamcity server?  This might give you more information.